# How to put brackets around a SQL result, via SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `sql` query inside the jasper report and I want to put brackets around a specific generated result from it .

This is sql query,

```
SELECT `idMedication`,`idPatient`, `Drug` from medication
```

I want to put a brackets around `Drug` from the result, and I require to do it via the SQL code it self.

For an example, at the moment a drug is displayed like "Paracetamol" but I require it as "`(Paracetamol)`"

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can use one of variants: 1) textField expression; 2) variable; 3) use concat in SQL query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the CONCAT function :

```
SELECT `idMedication`,`idPatient`, CONCAT('(', `Drug` ,')') AS Drug from medication
```

Comment: you could add `AS Drug` after your CONCAT() to make it easier to retreive afterward

Answer (score -1):

Very simple, use query like this

```
Select paracetamol As [(paracetamol)] from medication
```

It'll result as you require